# Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint

Tags: mysql

```
create database netflix;
use netflix;

create table usuario (
numero_documento_usuario varchar(15) not null,
primer_nombre_usuario varchar(15) not null,
segundo_nombre_usuario varchar(15),
primer_apellido_usuario varchar(15) not null,
segundo_apellido_usuario varchar(15),
email_usuario varchar(100) not null,
contraseña_usuario varchar(100) not null,
fk_id_tipo_documento varchar(15) not null,
fk_id_rol int not null,
fk_id_plan int not null
);
 
create table tipo_documento (
id_tipo_documento varchar(15) not null,
siglas varchar(5) not null,
nombre_tipo_documento varchar(30) not null,
primary key (id_tipo_documento)
);

create table rol (
id_rol int not null,
nombre_rol varchar(15) not null,
primary key (id_rol) 
);

create table plan (
id_plan int not null,
nombre_plan varchar(15) not null,
costo int not null,
primary key (id_plan)
);

create table perfil (
id_perfil int not null,
nombre_perfil varchar(15) not null,
avatar blob,
fk_numero_documento_usuario varchar(15) not null,
fk_id_tipo_documento varchar(15) not null
);

create table factura (
id_factura int not null,
fecha date not null,
hora time not null,
fk_numero_documento_usuario varchar(15) not null,
fk_id_tipo_documento varchar(15) not null,
fk_id_tipo_pago int not null
);

create table tipo_pago (
id_tipo_pago int not null,
nombre_pago varchar(30) not null,
primary key (id_tipo_pago)
);

create table series (
id_series int not null,
nombre_serie varchar(100) not null,
numero_temporadas tinyint(4) not null,
año year(4) not null,
sinopsis text not null,
calificacion float not null,
estado tinyint(4) not null,
primary key (id_series)
);

create table series_perfil (
fk_id_series int not null,
fk_id_perfil int
);

create table peliculas (
id_peliculas int not null,
nombre_pelicula varchar(100) not null,
duracion time not null,
año year not null,
sinpsis text not null,
estado tinyint(4) not null,
primary key (id_peliculas)
);

create table peliculas_perfil (
fk_id_peliculas int not null,
fk_id_perfil int not null
);

create table idioma (
id_idioma int not null,
nombre_idioma varchar(12) not null,
primary key (id_idioma)
);

create table temporadas (
id_temporadas int not null,
numero_temporadas tinyint(4) not null,
fk_id_series int not null
); 

create table capitulos (
id_capitulos int not null,
nombre_capitulos varchar(15) not null,
numero_capitulos tinyint(4) not null,
duracion time not null,
fk_id_temporadas int not null
);

create table capituos_idioma (
fk_id_capitulos int not null,
fk_id_idiomas int not null
);
 
create table peliculas_idioma (
fk_id_peliculas int not null,
fk_id_idioma int not null
);

create table categoria (
id_categoria int not null,
nombre_categoria varchar(75),
primary key (id_categoria)
);

create table categoria_peliculas (
fk_id_peliculas int not null,
fk_id_categorias int not null
);

create table categoria_serie (
kk_id_categoria int not null,                     
fk_id_serie int not null
);

create table servidor_correo (
id_servidor_correo int not null,
nombre_servidor_correo varchar(45) not null,
primary key (id_servidor_correo)
);

create table log_error (
id_error int not null,
descripcion_error varchar(200) not null,
fecha_hora_error datetime not null,
primary key (id_error)
);

alter table usuario add foreign key (fk_id_tipo_documento) references tipo_documento (id_tipo_documento);
alter table usuario add foreign key (fk_id_rol) references rol (id_rol);
alter table usuario add foreign key (fk_id_plan) references plan (id_plan);
alter table usuario add primary key (fk_id_tipo_documento, numero_documento_usuario);

alter table perfil add foreign key (fk_numero_documento_usuario) references usuario (numero_documento_usuario);
alter table perfil add foreign key (fk_id_tipo_documento) references tipo_documento (id_tipo_documento);
alter table perfil add primary key (id_perfil);

alter table factura add foreign key (fk_numero_documento_usuario) references usuario (numero_documento_usuario);
alter table factura add foreign key (fk_id_tipo_documento) references tipo_documento (id_tipo_documento);
alter table factura add foreign key (fk_id_tipo_pago) references tipo_pago (id_tipo_pago);
alter table factura add primary key (id_perfil);

alter table temporadas add foreign key (fk_id_series) references series (id_series);
alter table temporadas add primary key (id_temporadas); 

alter table capitulos add foreign key (fk_id_temporadas) references temporadas (id_temporadas);
alter table capitulos add primary key (id_capitulos);
```

Y me sale este erorrr:

> Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'perfil_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'usuario'

Pero ya he intentado hacer varias modificaciones pero nada, ayuda por favor.

Comment: ¿Por qué `numero_documento_usuario` no es llave primaria (PK)  en `usuario`? ¿Se admitirán varias filas con el mismo `numero_documento_usuario`? Como consejo, evita el uso de `ñ`, acentos y caracteres especiales en tus nombres de tablas/columnas.

Answer (score 0):

Inserta esta instrucción en la línea 155:

```
ALTER TABLE usuario ADD INDEX(numero_documento_usuario);
```

No puedes crear una clave ajena referenciada a un campo no indexado.

Mínimo `INDEX`, si necesitas `UNIQUE` o `PRIMARY KEY` ya es decisión tuya.

Te aparecerá otro error más adelante, pero ese ya te lo dejo a ti. Si no sabes cómo resolverlo, amplía la pregunta y ampliaré la respuesta.